# How to enable https on AWS ec2 Public IPv4 DNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, load-balancing

I have already mapped ip with domain name and its loading over ssl protocol.

However I wonder on enabling https also on the aws Public IPv4 DNS :

```
http://*.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Is it possible to redirect always to 443 port upon loading, same way as using for domain name that I own ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/?

Comment: above works only for. a domain that I manage.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to enable to redirect always to 443 port upon loading, same as using for domain name

Sadly its not possible as `compute.amazonaws.com` domain belongs to AWS, not you. You can only get valid SSL public certificate for a domain that you own or manage.

Comment: is there a way to hide it from the public or is there any alternative way :) ?

Comment: @gippo You can front your instance with CloudFront. It gives you HTTPs url for free. But all traffic between CF and the instance will be HTTP, as again you don't have your own domain with valid public SSL certificate.

Comment: I was thinking on redirecting to error message. 
is it possible to redirect to 503 or other fixed response ? if the path equals to *amazonaws.com? (in the load balancer : HTTP)

Comment: @gippo No. You can't modify error messages from load balancers.

Comment: @gippo Also if you have more questions, its better to make new SO question. I already answered correctly to your original query.